# Opentelemetry java Automatic Instrumentation with zipkin exporter option is using OtlpGrpcSpanExporter

Tags: java, spring-boot, zipkin, distributed-tracing, open-telemetry

I have a simple spring boot hello world application. Trying to send data to the Zipkin collector. But as per logs, it's trying to use `OtlpGrpcSpanExporter`. My application exposes a simple post rest API.

Following Opentelemetry
docs https://opentelemetry.io/docs/java/getting_started/

```
java -javaagent:tools/opentelemetry-javaagent-all.jar \
-Dotel.exporter=zipkin \
-jar target/*.jar
```

> [opentelemetry.auto.trace 2021-02-20 01:48:44:490 +0530] [grpc-default-executor-1] WARN io.opentelemetry.exporter.otlp.trace.OtlpGrpcSpanExporter - Failed to export spans. Error message: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
> [opentelemetry.auto.trace 2021-02-20 01:49:14:106 +0530] [grpc-default-executor-2] WARN io.opentelemetry.exporter.otlp.metrics.OtlpGrpcMetricExporter - Failed to export metrics
> io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception

Please let me know if I have to change anything.

Answer (score 4):

I get the same problem and below command did the trick.

```
java -javaagent:tools/opentelemetry-javaagent-all.jar \
-Dotel.traces.exporter=zipkin \
-jar target/*.jar
```

I checked the source code. It looks the property name has been changed:

https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/blob/14ace1ec32dbb194b8990763beb3ab6935849547/sdk-extensions/autoconfigure/src/main/java/io/opentelemetry/sdk/autoconfigure/TracerProviderConfiguration.java#L43

Answer (score 0):

This is the command that really worked for me.

```
-Dotel.traces.exporter=zipkin -Dotel.metrics.exporter=none -Dotel.exporter.zipkin.endpoint=http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans
```